# Find out actual disk usage in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, diskspace

Is there a way to find out how much space is consumed in HDFS?
I used

```
hdfs dfs -df
```

but it seems to be not relevant cause after deleting huge amount of data with

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash
```

the previous comand displays changes not at once but after several minutes (I need up-to-date disk usage info).

Comment: No solution?? Plase comment the answer that show a valid solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hadoop` cli is deprecated. Use `hdfs` instead.

Folder wise :

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -du -h /
```

Cluster wise :

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

Answer (score 7):

To see the space consumed by a particular folder try:

```
hadoop fs -du -s /folder/path
```

And if you want to see the usage, space consumed, space available, etc. of the whole HDFS:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Comment: Unfortunately `hadoop dfsadmin -report` shows not up-to-date info too.

Comment: ... And the correct command today (2019) is [`hdfs dfsadmin -report`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#dfsadmin)

Answer (score -1):

```
hadoop fs -count -q /path/to/directory
```